# Header Not Showing in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've built a collection view programmatically which is working fine however I am trying to add a header but nothing is showing up at the top for the header.
Here are the lines of code I have included which I understand to be important:

```
 collectionView.register(HeaderCollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: HeaderCollectionReusableView.identifier)
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: HeaderCollectionReusableView.identifier, for: indexPath) as! HeaderCollectionReusableView
        
        header.backgroundColor = .red
        
        return header
    }
```

```
    func collectionView(_collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
    }
```

I am not sure if I am missing some important code or if something is in the wrong place?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare collection view, UICollectionViewFlowLayout, cellId and headerId:

```
class YourController: UIViewController {

private var collectionView: UICollectionView?
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let cellId = "cellId"
let headerId = "headerId"
```

now in viewDidLoad set layout, collection and add constraints:

```
layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width / 2.2, height: view.bounds.size.width / 2.2) // set item size
    
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView?.delegate = self
collectionView?.dataSource = self
collectionView?.backgroundColor = .clear
collectionView?.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
collectionView?.register(MyHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)
collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
guard let collection = collectionView else { return }
    
view.addSubview(collection)
collection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
collection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
collection.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
collection.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Now in a separate Extension (the code is much clean) conform the collection delegate and datasource:

```
extension YourController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as! MyHeader
    
    header.configure()
    
    return header
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
 }
}
```

After that set your custom cell:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentView.backgroundColor = .link
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }
}
```

Now set the reusable view for header:

```
class MyHeader: UICollectionReusableView {

private let label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "This is the header"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .white
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return label
}()

public func configure() {
    backgroundColor = .systemGreen
    addSubview(label)
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
 }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! When I put in 'UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader' I get this error "Type 'UICollectionView' has no member 'elementKindSectionHeader'". I am not sure why this is (I am running Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)) and the closest thing I can find to put in instead is 'UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader'. Could you clarify if this is the correct thing to do?

Comment: @JoshPowrie have you conform your controller to UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocols? The code work like a charme, open new project. copy and paste my code in there and take a look...

Comment: @JoshPowrie please check my answer it's right answer and upvote :)